# Unable to import package

Tags: java, android

Hi I am working on an android project that requires File searching.
Now theres one problem that has arised -> I cannot import the package java.nio.file.*;
whatsoever even when I have installed jdk 7. Am using eclipse for android.
Plz help
Earlier I have changed **Window>preferences>java>compile>1.7**
The project compiles.
But when I changed **Project>properties>java compiler>1.7**
 
Then it gives me the following error
**"Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use 
Android Tools > Fix Project Properties."**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current android specifications require your project to be compiled under java 5 or java 6. Like Jason C has said, java 7 is not currently supported.

Unfortunately there isn't much way to bypass this restriction (if you intend to publish your application) so your stuck with rewriting any java 7 code (empty <> operation, try-with-resources, etc) into java 6.

Comment: Sorry... nope... Look into other libraries or program your own.

Comment: @user2160540 And btw... looking at your other comments... The java compiler is perfectly capable of compiling for a lower version than it actually is. For example, adding the parameter -source 1.6 to javac will cause it to produce Java 6 bytecode which is all the android project requires.

Comment: No this is irritating! Thanks though!! Used saved me time!

Comment: Hi now I am changing the code to suite the so called "android need for jdk 6" but now I want to change the code here http://http://stackoverflow.com/a/13990938 but then that points me out that I need commonsIO included in my project. Well I downloaded it included it in the references but still the package import org.apache.common.io does not get resolved whatsover is there something more that I need to do .. inorder to make it work?

Comment: @user2160540 Try downloading the source and adding it to your project's source directly... That way you'll know if it uses any java 7 features.

Comment: Well I need to get it running before I can include it! Eclipse says cannot resolve it!

Comment: @user2160540 I'm not sure if you misunderstood me but what I meant was, rather than including a reference to the library, download the source for Apache Commons IO (it's should be released open source) and directly include it in your projects source path (in the case for eclipse, basically drop it into the "src" folder). All references should be resolved in that case and all problems relating to java 7 will also pop up.

Comment: well you mean including the .java files directly other than the .class ones? Well It commons-io-2.4-src.zip in the libs folder and the same in referenced libraries.... Just incase I was messing with the versions yet again!

Comment: @user2160540 Yes, include the java source files from Commons IO directly into your project. Extract all zip files until your left with a folder structure that goes something like org/apache/commons/io. If you have further problems, you can start a chat with me. Lets not spam the comments.

Comment: Hey Buddy that worked out finally I was actually leaving it to a zip!! Well I took eclipse for granted lol It required me to extract the .zip n then importing the actual commonsio.jar to the libs!! :)

Comment: @user2160540 Glad it worked out in the end... Once again, if you have any questions relating to this topic, either research first (if that fails post a new question) or if you feel its a small thing, contact me via chat. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 3):

Android does not currently support Java 7.

The [system requirements for the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) currently specify Java 6.

Comment: Am sorry to ask but how come you understood something like this that I have JAVA 7 installed. I have JDK7

Comment: JDK 7 is Java 7's JDK. Version 1.7 is Java 7.

Comment: Ok so does that mean I need to install a former version of JAVA with jdk 1.7 for importing java.nio.file?

Comment: @user2160540: No, it means you can't use java.nio.file. There's no such thing as "a former version of Java with JDK 1.7". If it's JDK 1.7, it's Java 7. You'll have to use 1.6 (or JDK6 or Java 6 or whatever you prefer to call it). Java 6 does not have java.nio.file.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it to me! I thought JDK n JAVA versions differed!!

Answer (score 1):

Android Systems only support java versions upto `Java 6` and hence the builder is complaining for  it. In builder you can create different kind of projects(non-android also), hence it allows to set the java compiler preferences to version 1.7 in windows menu. But if you try to set the java compiler version to 1.7 for an android project, it will not let you.

Comment: Ohh thats the fuss all about!! Thanks Juned

Comment: Heck so that means I need to install JAVA 6 , n remove JAVA 7 is it?But then will java 6 use jdk 1.7? This is confussing

Comment: @user2160540 No no no, android project will support only java compiler version i.e jdk1.6. So there is no way that you can make it run with higher version. Even if you somehow hack it to use jdk 1.7, it will actually fail on the device because device cannot run a java version higher than 6. Btw device will use jre to run the code and not jdk, if that is also a confusion.

Answer (score -1):

Android SDK is not x64. So it will not support java7. It will check for any compatible version like java5.java6. So choose java6. That's why you've got this problem. Try Fix Project Properties, if still getting error change version 1.7 to 1.6 from project > properties > java compiler > 1.6!

Comment: The OP is trying to use java.nio.file.*, which is new in Java 7, but Android does not support Java 7, only up to 6. 32- vs. 64-bit is not related.

Comment: Yep buddy! Was editing the answer and someone downvoted! :( Also I mentioned it because Android SDK isn't x64 but it works with x64 eclipse IDE. So using Fix Project Properties it would work, as fixing properties it uses compiler level 1.6..

Comment: Your Answer is still wrong.  The reason that Android doesn't support Java 7 is nothing to do with x64.