# How can I make my apk to function only if my device has a txt file?

Tags: javascript, android, security, authentication, text

How can I make my apk to function only if my device has a txt file?
I have an apk that I have made.

Is there a way to make it work only if the device its installed on has a specific text file which I can input anything in and it won't work if the device doesn't have the file.

Comment: Java or Javascript?

Comment: Note that if you mean it as some kind of a security measure, anything that you check in/about the file will be part of your app, so it will be relatively easy for an attacker to "crack" (reverse engineer) your app and find out what needs to be where for the app to work. So such a solution has almost zero security value.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for your file in `onCreate` method of your launcher activity. If the file exists, you can do whatever you want like creating an intent to `MainActivity` and if it does not exist, you can finish your app :

```
File file = new File(filePath);
if(file.exists()) {
    // Do Something 
}
else {
    // Close the app
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Wow,  thanks but how do I specify the path of the text since its for different devices.

Comment: @flochristos If your are the one who saved the text file, then you can store it's path somewhere like shared preferences otherwise you can search user's SD card to check if the file exists : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990826/android-how-to-search-files-on-sd-card